# Unable to connect NodeJS on VPS to MySQL on another hosting

Tags: mysql, node.js, centos, firewall, iptables

I deployed my nodejs app on a VPS but it can't connect to my MySQL database hosted in another server but it works in my PC and another VPS .

I decided to test that connection doing this:

```
nmap -p 3306 mysqlserver.com 
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp filtered mysql
```

When I tried it in my personal computer I got:

```
nmap -p 3306 mysqlserver.com 
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp open mysql
```

I can connect succesfully  to remote mysql on my PC

iptables

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1226/sshd           
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1282/postgres       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1543/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::48937                :::*                    LISTEN      2572/node           
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1229/httpd          
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1226/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 :::5432                 :::*                    LISTEN      1282/postgres       
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      1543/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::47135                :::*                    LISTEN      2572/node           
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           604/avahi-daemon: r 
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54701           0.0.0.0:*                           604/avahi-daemon: r 
[root@host1 /]# iptables -L -n -v
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
84363 8756K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    3   180 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 8791  554K INPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 8791  554K INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 8791  554K INPUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 1163 41912 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
  405 79341 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:3306 dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:3306 ctstate ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306 state NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_IN_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FORWARD_OUT_ZONES  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 9878 packets, 1240K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
72617   11M OUTPUT_direct  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   14   616 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      eth0    0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:3306 state ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  ens160 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDI_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      ens160  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 FWDO_public  all  --  *      +       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDI_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDI_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDI_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDI_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 FWDO_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 FWDO_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FWDO_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FWDO_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_ZONES (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 8791  554K IN_public  all  --  ens160 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 
    0     0 IN_public  all  --  +      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           [goto] 

Chain INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public (2 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 8791  554K IN_public_log  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 8791  554K IN_public_deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
 8791  554K IN_public_allow  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:21 ctstate NEW
  230 13572 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306 ctstate NEW
   25  1120 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5025 ctstate NEW
 6968  418K ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:5432 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3306 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3001 ctstate NEW
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3030 ctstate NEW

Chain IN_public_deny (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain IN_public_log (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT_direct (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

I need to request mysqlserver.com : 3306 in my VPS

Is this being blocked by the firewall?

I'm using % in mysql access host list

Node JS connection

```
var db_config = {
    host: "mysqlserver.com",
    port: 3306,
    user: "user",
    password: "pass",
    database: "database",
};
```

I tried to request to another server and I got "Open"

```
nmap -p 3306 myOtherHosting.com
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
3306/tcp open      mysql
```

Comment: Do you use the `cPanel` to manage your site?

Comment: Yes, the mySQL server use cPanel

Comment: Try editing your your Config Server Firewall (by editing the `csf.conf` file) and add your IP address to that. Hope that will resolve the issue.

Comment: You can add something like => `csf -a 192.168.1.109` (Replace `192.168.1.109` withour actual IP address)

Comment: I added the domain name and the ip and it does not seem to work ( I restarted the csf) :(

Comment: You updated it with your **machine's** ip address right? (I mean no the one which I've gave in the example 192.168.1.109) ?